# Merge one dataframe with a date vector

Tags: r, date, merge

I would like to create a dataframe merging the dataframe `ss` to a vector `daily_vector`, with date information, through the column `"ss$Date_R"`. I would like to keep all rows from `daily_vector` to know which date in the dataframe `ss` has no data. I have tried use the function `merge`however when I tried it the vector apears as a list of numbers and not like the date.

The column `"ss$Date_R"` is a character column buecause I concatenated the information of the years, months and days.

```
head(ss)
                         Station Variable Value     Date_R
    1    SAN VICENTE DEL PALACIO    TMAX1    90 1985-01-01
    910  SAN VICENTE DEL PALACIO    TMAX2    90 1985-01-02
    1819 SAN VICENTE DEL PALACIO    TMAX3   110 1985-01-03
    2728 SAN VICENTE DEL PALACIO    TMAX4    85 1985-01-04
    3637 SAN VICENTE DEL PALACIO    TMAX5   110 1985-01-05
    4546 SAN VICENTE DEL PALACIO    TMAX6   100 1985-01-06
str(ss)
'data.frame':   9418 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Station : Factor w/ 3 levels "MEDINA DE RIOSECO",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Variable: Factor w/ 31 levels "TMAX1","TMAX2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Value   : int  90 90 110 85 110 100 80 30 80 70 ...
 $ Date_R  : chr  "1985-01-01" "1985-01-02" "1985-01-03" "1985-01-04" ...


daily_vector <-as.factor(seq(as.Date("1985-01-01"), as.Date("2010-10-14"), by="days"))
```

Does someone know how I can merge these two kinds of information?
Do you know a better way to know which day are absent in the dataframe `ss`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need a second dataframe instead of a vector with column as `Date_R` and then `merge` by `Date_R`

Comment: I have tried to create a dataframe with two variables (the same vector repeated with different colnames), however when I did it. The data is converted to numeric (1,2,3...)

Comment: Can you, with `dput`, provide a portion of your data and daily_vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to to check the dates in `daily_vector` not in `ss$Date_R`, you don't need to add a new column. Instead, you can use

```
ss$Date_R <- as.Date(ss$Date_R)    
daily_vector <- seq(as.Date("1985-01-01"), as.Date("2010-10-14"), by="days")
missing <- !daily_vector %in% ss$Date_R 
daily_vector[missing]
```

This will return the dates missing in `ss$Date_R` as a simple vector of dates.

Edit: To add the rows of missing dates to your dataframe, you can use merge as follows:

```
daily_ex <- daily_vector[1:6] # 6 total dates
ss <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(5), V2=rnorm(5),
            Date_R=c(daily_vector[c(1:4, 6)])) # 5 total rows, skipped date #5 on purpose
Date_R_all <- data.frame(Date_R = daily_ex)
merge(ss, Date_R_all, by="Date_R", all=TRUE)
```

The result is

```
1 1985-01-01 -0.2152378 -1.1546424
2 1985-01-02  0.7188043 -0.3882131
3 1985-01-03  0.9581949  1.2717832
4 1985-01-04 -0.6559881 -0.6670120
5 1985-01-05         NA         NA
6 1985-01-06 -0.6285255 -1.2645569
```

Comment: It works perfectly to check which data is absent!!!
But finally I need to get the dataframe. It would be possible to get the result in a dataframe with the values and the NAs? 
It is because I would like to interpolate new data in the NAs cells with the previous and next value.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think the `merge` way is ok, but first: (a) you need to set the class of your Date_R column to "Date"; (b) your daily_vector must be a data.frame (`?merge` for further information). Try the follows:

```
ss$Date_R <- as.Date.character(ss$Date_R)
daily <-data.frame((seq(as.Date("1985-01-01"),as.Date("2010-10-14"),by="days")))
colnames(daily_vec) <- "Date_R"
merge(ss, daily_vector, all=TRUE)
```